# Visualize/Analyze the difference between graph networks

Tags: social-network-analysis, graphical-model

I'm newbie in Data Analyst. I am studying Computational Neuroscience. I have the two figures. A short description about the experiment is: an animal do a task with two conditions. I have a calcium imaging data for several days at 12 regions of brain like M1, M2,...
At each day, I report the core complex network: with visible nodes are active nodes and shaded nodes are inactive nodes. The edges between them measure the correlation. I want to find a way to visualize or analyze the different of the networks between two cue conditions (CueA vs. CueB) and highlight the important part of the network. Any idea to do so?
Thank you so much.
[image: network_cueA]
[image: network_cueB]